# Bulk Update of Custom Post Type Post Status through SQL

Tags: database, sql, post-status

The following code updates the post status of standard wordpress posts to 'Archived'.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'Archived' WHERE post_status != 'static';
```

How can I make this only affect custom post types with the slug of 'cpt_operator'. I know I can do this from Wp-Admin but with over 2,500 posts its a huge task.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean post type instead of slug I'd say...

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_status = 'archived'
WHERE post_status <> 'static'
AND post_type = 'cpt_operator';
```

But be careful when editing the db directly!